# Add OpenSC PKCS#11 security module in firefox globally through the CLI

Tags: firefox

I can follow these instructions to add the [OpenSC PKCS#11](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Installing-OpenSC-PKCS%2311-Module-in-Firefox,-Step-by-Step) module manually to the Firefox Security Module through the GUI. But would like to add it via the CLI so I can script it but I'm not able to find where the Firfox nsstools stores it. On top of that it seems to only seems to add the Security Module to my profile on the machine instead of globally for everyone.